# Country wins war by inventing ray that destroys paper

Tags: story-identification

The 1972 edition of *The Readers Digest Treasury of American Humor*, in an introduction to a section on bureaucracy, contains the words:

> I once read a science-fiction story about a great war between Country A and Country B. A licked B without any blood being spilled. Its army used a secret weapon - a ray that only destroyed paper.

Are there any ideas what this story could be? I assume that this is a short story, but it could equally well be a novel or novella.

Comment: Now that all offices are fully electronic and totally paper-free, the plot is totally obsolete.

Comment: It's not the one you're looking for, but it reminded me of The Ayes of Texas by Daniel da Cruz. The destruction of paperwork in Washington DC and Moscow is a plot point in there (pr possibly in the sequel, it's been a while). They don't use a ray, though. It's a biological agent, if memory serves.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson Now we'd use an EMP to fry all (civilian) computers.

Comment: @Michael: yes, totally "paper-free" .. O.o  wow, you really don't work in an office, do you .. lol

Comment: My answer was meant to be tongue-in-cheek.  I do work in an office.

Comment: There's a similar weapon destroying paper used in the novel Erich Kästner, *Die Konferenz der Tiere* (1949), but it does not win the war, and is also not science fiction.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This sounds like Poul Anderson's "[The Perfect Weapon](https://www.unz.org/Pub/AnalogSF-1950feb-00046?View=Overview)".

> Bureaucracy, the hallmark of all modern nations, was seized upon as a
>   symbol of the totalitarian state in a similar story, "The Perfect
>   Weapon" (Feb 1950), by Poul Anderson, then beginning his long career
>   as a successful science-fiction writer. Like Smith, Anderson felt that
>   a dictatorship’s mania for paperwork was its weak spot, and postulated
>   a weapon that would destroy only paper, assuming that a free society
>   would need less paperwork to survive since it had fewer laws to
>   enforce. - <sub><sup>http://www.depauw.edu/sfs/backissues/9/berger9art.htm</sup></sub>

Comment: Wouldn't work anymore!

Comment: @Shane - I've yet to come across an office that's paperless. Most of the places I've worked would have suffered badly if all of their paper had suddenly disappeared.

Comment: I don't think I've come across offices that the paper wasn't a printout of something on a computer though.

Comment: Well, if it also affected all paper currency, it could have a pretty significant economic effect.  Even if everyone's accounts are stored electronically, it would take years for the mints to recreate all of the destroyed cash, during which time people would be unable to access it.  As usual, the poor would take the brunt of it, as they're less likely to have bank accounts.  The biggest tragedy would be the loss of all the books in all the libraries - Only a small percentage of all books in history have been digitized so far...

Comment: Law courts will probably rely on paper for a long time.

Comment: @Shane what about the post-it notes?

Comment: @Richard I've worked in several different programming jobs where, if all the paper suddenly vanished, it would have a minor-to-negligible effect on the workplace.

Comment: Guys its a joke! @Oxinabox Touché!

Comment: @MasonWheeler - I suspect your complacency would vanish the moment you didn't get paid at the end of the month because your payroll is paid by cheque to the bank.

Comment: @Richard What is this "cheque" of which you speak?  It's all direct deposit these days, transferring electrons from one computer to another, and has been for a loooooong time now.

Comment: @MasonWheeler - The problem is that *your job* might be largely paper free, but can you be 100% sure that **every job** in your company is paper free?

Comment: This seems to be the best match possible... I can't state with certainty that this is it, but it certainly ticks all the boxes

Comment: @PeterPeter - If only there was somewhere you could go to download the original story; https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v44n06_1950-02_dtsg0318

Comment: @DarrelHoffman 'Paper' currency isn't actually made of normal paper. [Typically it's made of 'cotton paper'.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banknote#Materials_used_for_banknotes). So if the weapon only targeted wood-pulp paper then banknotes would be fine.

Comment: @Pharap the weapon loosens the strength of cellulose connections, so I assume cotton paper would be fine.

Comment: @PeterPeter In that case they might not be 'fine', and neither would photographs using celluloid. [Cellulose is the main ingredient of textiles made from cotton, linen, and other plant fibers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellulose#Applications)